# Whats the relation between load and for?

Tags: tsung

I am trying `tsung` for the first time, however, I need some clarification.

I am using load tag as:

```
<load>
    <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="1" unit="minute">
        <users maxnumber="100000" interarrival="0.01" unit="second"/>
    </arrivalphase>
</load>
```

But, how would the `for` loop below works ?:

```
 <sessions>
<session name="root" probability="100" type="ts_http">
   <for from="1" to="2" var="i">

       <request>
           <http url="/test/counter" method="POST" contents="bla=blu&amp;name=glop">
           </http>
       </request>

   </for>
  </session>
```

What I thought is that the loop will count from 1 to 2, thus, sending only two requests, however, when I run the xml file, I got hundred of requests! Does this mean that each user in `arrivalphase` will send two requests as in the for loop above?

Can someone explain, what's the relation between the `for` tag and `load` tag as in the above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is right , during the first 1 minute of the test , you created 100 users per second，each user will send two requests as in the for loop above。

The load define tsung generate rules of the user, the session define every user needs to perform logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to pump the server with 1000 user per second, each with a post request, however, I've noticed that number of hits on the testing server is far less than what I expected, what do you suggest to check?

Comment: @simo Is the server cannot be received 1000 requests, or cannot create 1000 users? maybe the number of users have a limit , try to check the attribute of maxnumber and maxusers , you can set loglevel = debug,check the log